# Prove that an Isometric Linear Transformation will always have an invariant line.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This question was asked in an interview. The linear algebra course I studied didn't cover Isometric Transformation, I struggled with this question. However, I tried to reason it with Eigenvectors.

I have searched the web for possible proofs.

Can anyone give some hints on how to go about it?

Comment: Is this on a finite-dimensional space? Real? Complex? Bear in mind that a rotation in $\Bbb{R}^2$, by any angle other than a multiple of $\pi$, will leave no line invariant, since it will map any line to a completely different line.

Comment: Do you mean in $\mathbb R^3?$

Comment: I assumed $\Bbb R^3$ as it was not specified by the interviewer.

Answer (score 1):

See [the Wikipedia article on Euler’s rotation theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem)